# Convert posts that used the Markdown Block into Markdown in Classic Editor posts?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, markdown

I’m wondering if anyone has any ideas, or even solutions, for wanting to convert all the posts I wrote using the Markdown Block before I disabled Gutenberg into Markdown in Classic Editor posts, so all my content matches under the hood.

If you’ve never seen the difference, Markdown Block posts when viewed in the Classic editor start with a section of Markdown wrapped in

```
<!-- wp:jetpack/markdown {"source":"[the markdown]"} -->
```

followed by

```
<div class="wp-block-jetpack-markdown">[the html]</div>
```

whereas Markdown in Classic Editor posts when viewed in the Classic editor just straight-up has the Markdown as written, cleanly.

I gather that Markdown for Classic Editor stores the Markdown in `post_content_filtered` and the HTML in `post_content`, loading the former into the editor when you edit a post.

By what I see when I load a Markdown Block post into the Classic Editor, that’s not how things are stored when using Markdown Block. Is there a `post_content_filtered` on posts written in Markdown Block at all? It seems more like that entire thing above is just saved in regular `post_content`.

Anyway, if anyone’s got any suggestions on how I could convert all those Markdown Block entries to Markdown in Classic Editor entries, I’m all ears. Thanks.